# Android 5.0+ doesn't change checkbox image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm trying to make a custom multi image pick gallery. When I click on the `CheckBox` logs show me, that everything has to work: `OnCheckedChanged` and `OnClick` callbacks are fired, but there's no animation or even simple changing picture, I tried to manually call `view.invalidate()` but it doesn't work too. I think that this is kind of AppCompat library bug? I've found, that everything works perfectly before 5.0.

Here is part of the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

And here is layout.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <include layout="@layout/recycler_view_item_picture"/>

  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/checked"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="end|top"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is styles.xml:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
```

Here is holder code:

```
public class PictureChooserItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  @Bind(R.id.checked) CheckBox mChecked;
  @Bind(R.id.image) ImageView mImage;    

  public PictureChooserItem(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
  }

  @OnClick(R.id.image) public void onClick(View v) {
    Timber.d("OnClick!");
  }

  @OnCheckedChanged(R.id.checked) public void onCheckedChange(CompoundButton v, boolean flag) {
    Timber.d("OnChecked!");
  }

  public void bindFromCursor(Context ctx, Cursor cursor) {

    final int dataColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

    final GalleryUtils.GalleryImage item =
        new GalleryUtils.GalleryImage(cursor.getString(dataColumnIndex));
    Glide.with(ctx).load(item.path).asBitmap().placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(mImage);
  }
}
```

Here is adapter code (I use subclass of [this](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)):

```
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(PictureItem viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
  viewHolder.bindFromCursor(mContext, cursor);
}
```

Here is screenshot[image]

Comment: question is off-topic ... please add minimal code example ... like createViewHolder and bindViewHolder implementation

Comment: @Selvin I added holder code, I ain't sure it will help you

Comment: @Selvin also i added bind method from adapter

Comment: @AntonShkurenko show your style class

Comment: hmm so this is not problem with scrolling/recycling? you just check a checkbox and "visually" nothing happens?

Comment: @Selvin hm, really, I've found, that it doesn't scroll, but it scrolls in <5.0. But onclicks are fired

Comment: @AntonShkurenko everything is looking fine. I am not getting that why it is not clicking so i will suggest try to add this line in you style and call it in checkbox. Well its not needed but you can try once.
<style name="AppTheme.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/almanac_red_dark</item>
    </style>   in values-21 folder

Comment: @Aashvi I've discovered that it doesn't scroll, I'll try your solution, thanks

Comment: @Selvin also, I changed build.gradle to 22.2.0 version and now everything works, but I want 23 build tools

Comment: @Aashvi I changed version to 22.2.0 and now everything works, but how to change it to 23.1.1

Comment: @AntonShkurenko good.

Comment: Build minimal example and post on bugtrack https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: Oook, I will report it at the a couple of hours later. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, we've found the answer.

Migrating from the support fragments to the 4.0+ fragments did the job.

An issue was about support fragment manager. Calling:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

Also helps.